# Nhibernate proper multithread session handling in recursive structure

Tags: c#, multithreading, session, nhibernate, concurrency

I have some recursive structure like:

```
Folder+
      |
      +A+AA+AAA
           +AAB
           +AAC
        +AB
        +AC
      +B
      +C
```

And i want this structure to be processed with multiple threads so i utilized TPL Dataflow like this:

```
     m_dataOperationQueue = new ActionBlock<Folder>(x => ProcessFolder(x)
            , new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 });
```

and when i process some folder i want to

1. Save processing result into database
2. Update each child and add them some result from completed item processing
3. Delete processed folder from database
4. Enqueue child folders for processing

What i strugle with is Nhibernate session management and i get a lot of errors - mostly session is closed.

For session management i use NHibernateIntegration with windsor castle with AutoTX facility **BUT** i have access to original NHibernate sessionFactory. What would be proper way of handling these operations and how manage session in this scenario to avoid session closing.

my save operation looks like this:

```
    [Transaction(TransactionMode.Requires)]
    public virtual Folder SaveNewFolder(Folder folder)
    {
        using (var session = SessionManager.OpenSession())
        {
           session.Save(folder); //At this line i have most errors
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few of issues in your approach,

1. When you do recursive saving of folders, you do save the parent folder first and enqueue the child folders for processing, but the problem would be when you persist A NHibernate will go ahead and persist all AA,AAA,AAB...,AB... hierarchy simply because A would have reference to AA..AB. So saving child folders in separate thread won't work as they have already persisted, and in the other thread A is not properly persisted.
2. And once you do the processing of the parent folder, it's deleted. When you delete parent most likely the child entities also will be deleted and in another thread you are trying to persist child entity where parent entity is deleted and this would be very confusing for NhHbernate.

Comment: Oh i know all about 1 and 2. What i do is I SAVE whole structure to db and then i want to enqueue Top level for processing. Also when i finish processing of parrent i am NOT deleting children (no cascade here) i ll only update and make child orphaned -> thus making them new parrents